# Hydraulic disc brakes transportation

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, transportation

I'm planning on packing my bike for transportation with both wheels off. I have SRAM Apex disc brakes on the bike. What are the risks if ever the brake leavers get squeezed during transportation ?

Answer (score 6):

The risk is that you'll need to spread the pads before you can re-insert the wheels. You can get disc-brake spacers to keep the pads separate for transport, and I recommend using them.

Comment: Another risk is over-extending the piston and possibly leaking.

Comment: Spacers can be anything that won’t contaminate the pad. E.g clean cardboard folded a few times and held in place with a rubber band. Ice cream sticks are about right too.